# How to dynamically append data to a webpage after API call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a webpage that, given a user input, returns a list of results from wikipedia. I have gotten the call to Wikipedia's API to work fine, but when I attempt to append the data to my webpage, it flickers on for a split second and then disappears. I suspect it has to do with the event handlers, but I have tried several alternatives without luck. I also looked around SO and the web at large but could not find a solution. Here is my code:

```
var results = [];

$("#search").on("keydown", "#searchinput", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    var searchParameter = encodeURIComponent(this.value);
    var link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchParameter + "&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*";

    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {
      for (var key in data) {
        results.push(data[key]);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
          $("#results").append(results[i][j]);
        }
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide! I am happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Your `if` statement only surrounds the first 2 lines of the event handler.

Comment: Shouldn't the call to `$.getJSON` be inside the `if`? Otherwise you're calling it without setting `link`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `$.getJSON` should be in the `if` block with the variable assignments.

```js
var results = [];

$("#search").on("keydown", "#searchinput", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    var searchParameter = encodeURIComponent(this.value);
    var link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchParameter + "&limit=10&namespace=0&format=json&origin=*";

    $.getJSON(link, function(data) {
      for (var key in data) {
        results.push(data[key]);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < results[i].length; j++) {
          $("#results").append(results[i][j]);
        }
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
  <input id="searchinput" type="text">
</div>
<div id="results">

</div>
```

Comment: The call to $.getJSON was working previously, but I have edited the question to reflect the proper formatting. It still does not append properly to my webpage.

Comment: It works for me. If the page is clearing after this runs, it's some other code on your page.

Comment: Is the input field in a `<form>`? Make sure you're not submitting the form, since that will reload the page.

Comment: You can set a DOM modification breakpoint to trigger when something modifies `#results`. Then when the breakpoint is hit outside this code, you'll know what's doing it.

Comment: It was inside of a form element. Thank you!!